# C# : Interface without Namespace

Tags: c#

I generated an interface based off a WSDL definition file with wsdl.exe to use with a project.  The resulting generated .cs file has the expected interface inside it, but the interface file doesn't have a namespace - the interface definition is directly below the using statements.

I've never seen a source code file without an explicitly declared namespace, which leads me to wonder: what are the benefits and drawbacks of not explicitly declaring a namespace?  Is this a common thing to do with generated code?

Comment: This interface will be available on the global namespace. See http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/archive/2008/05/30/global-namespace-in-c.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The benefits are, I guess, less time spent typing in a namespace...  You are able to specify the namespace you want as a parameter with `wsdl.exe`, and you should do so:

```
wsdl.exe /namespace:foo http://myreference/
```

The drawback is that without a namespace, you're that much more likely to have naming collisions with your objects.  This problem gets more severe the more consumers there are of your class or interface.  A namespace is definitely a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Usually code-generators have properties to specify namespace for the generated code. Namespaces provide logical grouping of the types, so they of course should be used to avoid ambiguities.

Answer (score 1):

Namespaces are there to help you organise you're code and, primarily, to avoid naming collisions.

I would imagine there will be a way to specify the namespace for the generated code?